# Promise.resolve with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have the following code. Its purpose is to take data from a database and format it into JSON objects so that they can be compatible with VueCal.

I am requesting data from the database, then taking each result and creating a JSON object, pushing that object to an array, then using `Promise.resolve([array name])` to hopefully return that array with the promise.

I wrap this in a `Promise.all` block and then add all these resolved promises into another array. This final array contains 4 undefined elements. Why is this?

```
try {
    const results = await Promise.all([
      Budget.find({
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail
      })
        .then(budgets => {
          let budgetsFormatted = []
          for (let i = 0; i < budgets.length; i++) {
            if (budgets[i].startDate) {
              var startBegin = moment(budgets[i].startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
              var endBegin = moment(budgets[i].startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(1, 'hour')
              var startEnd = moment(budgets[i].startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(budgets[i].duration, 'days')
              var endEnd = moment(budgets[i].startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(1, 'hour')
            } else {
              continue
            }
            budgetsFormatted.push({
              title: budgets[i].title,
              start: startBegin,
              end: endBegin,
              content: octicons.credit_card + '<br>£' + budgets[i].amount
            })
            budgetsFormatted.push({
              title: budgets[i].title,
              start: startEnd,
              end: endEnd,
              content: octicons.credit_card + '<br>£' + budgets[i].amount
            })
          }
          console.log(budgetsFormatted)
          Promise.resolve(budgetsFormatted)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Promise.reject(err)
        }),

      Notes.find({
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail
      })
        .then(notes => {
          let notesFormatted = []
          for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            if (notes[i].dateCreated) {
              var start = moment(notes[i].dateCreated, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
              var end = moment(notes[i].dateCreated, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(1, 'hour')
            } else {
              continue
            }
            notesFormatted.push({
              title: notes[i].title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              content: octicons.note + '<br>' + notes[i].body.substr(1, 10) + '...'
            })
          }
          console.log(notesFormatted)
          Promise.resolve(notesFormatted)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Promise.reject(err)
        }),

      StudyPlan.find({
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail
      })
        .then(studyplan => {
          let studyPlansFormatted = []
          for (let i = 0; i < studyplan.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < studyplan[i]['daysAndTimes'].length; j++) {
              if (studyplan[i]['daysAndTimes'].timeFrom) {
                var start = moment(studyplan[i]['daysAndTimes'].timeFrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
                var end = moment(studyplan[i]['daysAndTimes'].timeFrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(studyplan[i]['daysAndTimes'].duration, 'hours')
              } else {
                continue
              }
              studyPlansFormatted.push({
                title: studyplan[i].title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                content: octicons.pencil
              })
            }
          }
          console.log(studyPlansFormatted)
          Promise.resolve(studyPlansFormatted)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Promise.reject(err)
        }),

      TodoList.find({
        userEmail: req.body.userEmail
      })
        .then(todolists => {
          let todoListsFormatted = []
          for (let i = 0; i < todolists.length; i++) {
            if (todolists[i].dateDue) {
              var start = moment(todolists[i].dateDue, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
              var end = moment(todolists[i].dateDue, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').add(1, 'hours')
            } else {
              continue
            }

            todoListsFormatted.push({
              title: todolists[i].title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              content: octicons.tasklist
            })
          }
          console.log(todoListsFormatted)
          Promise.resolve(todoListsFormatted)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Promise.reject(err)
        })
    ])

    const events = [].concat.apply([], results)
```

EDIT:

Ill leave the code there incase anyone want to look at it. But this is the basic structure of the code:

```
const results = await Promise.all([
  //Find data in Database
  |
   ->  //Format result to be a JSON object like the following:
        {
          title: 'Event Title',
          start: //Start date of event,
          end: //End date of event,
          content: '<content> of event object in </calendar>'
        }
        //Add this object into array
        Promise.resolve(the above referenced array)

  //Repeat the above for each collection in the database

])

const events = [].concat.apply([], results)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Try reducing it to a more simple case that could be extended to your actual problem.

Comment: @FranciscoHanna done

Comment: Have you tried removing `await` and handling the `Promise.all` with `then`?

Comment: And what is this line for `[].concat.apply([], results)`? Why you don't just use the `results` array?

Comment: I just tried handling it with `then` and it is still just returning an array of  `null`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return a result in each Promise handler. That is why elements in results are undefined

```
return Promise.resolve(budgetsFormatted)
```

Comment: Why create a new promise with `Promise.resolve()`? `then` already returns a promise.